# Can file upload and download be possible when using the Flutter_Webview package?

Tags: flutter, webview

I would like to ask if file upload and download are possible when using the Flutter_Webview package.

I have granted WRITE and READ permissions in the 'AndroidManifest.xml', but there is no response when I run the code. Upon searching, I found that there are limitations in the Flutter_Webview package that prevent file upload and download, and that I should use the Flutter_Webview_Plugin package instead. However, it seems difficult to use as the package is not currently being updated.

I am wondering if I am misunderstanding something or if there are any additional settings that need to be made. Thank you for your response!